# How do I make the currently-selected UI element more obvious in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface

I'm looking for a way to increase the visibility of the currently-selected UI element in Chrome and/or Chromium.

This is how it looks for me by default. There is a thin blue outline around the button:

[image: default]

This is how I would like it to look:

[image: better]

I tried searching for extensions, but "highlight" seems to exclusively refer to increasing the visibility of text-segments.

Is there any way to accomplish this?